# IntelliJ IDEA missing some classes in autocomplete

Tags: intellij-idea

I have quite a few libraries attached to my project and in Eclipse it shows me all my classes that are available to me when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>.
But with IntelliJ IDEA so many are missing and even when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> twice it still does not show up.

How ever it does come up when I use goto class(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>) it fines it ill add 2 print screens as an example: 
[image: Not Finding class]

[image: Finding class in goto]

Comment: The libraries may be attached to the project, but are they attached to the module you're currently working on? If they are not listed as dependencies of the module you're currently working on, then they won't show up in code-completion (though because they are attached to the project, they will show up in ctrl+n).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Opened up a bug on the jetbrains tracker and Peter Gromov got back to me with "its a bug to do with starting a class with a small letter." The said bug is [documented here](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-110221#)

Peter suggested that I use the new version of Intellij Idea 13 in which this issue was fixed.

**Update**
It works on Intellij Idea 13 (as suggested by Peter), so indeed it was an issue with the first character being a lower case character.

Answer (score 2):

By default IntelliJ IDEA come with a "first letter" case sensitive. Here's the place to change that value to "None".

[image: Case insensitive]

Comment: That was not the issue. It was a bug and fixed in the latest version.
If you look at my print screens you will see that my case was spot on it just did not show the related class. Though depending on coding style its a very important setting.